# Class with same code and send data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this C# class to send the data from *DriveInfo* Class to my window form:

```
using System;

public class FileSystemInfo
{

    public string CheckTotalFreeSpace()
    {

        System.IO.DriveInfo DInfo = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\");
        return DInfo.TotalFreeSpace.ToString();
    }

    public string CheckVolumeLabel()
    {
        System.IO.DriveInfo DInfo = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"C:\");
        return DInfo.VolumeLabel.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to send huge data from one class (see my example) into my form class (maybe labels or ListBox Control), by using a a good way to solve this issue. Also I don't want to put this line of code into separate c# class method:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo DInfo
```

The basic issue for me is: deal and show many info about my computer so I need to put all this info into one structure or something else.

Comment: VolumeLabel is already a string, so a lot of this makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Lazy` class:

```
using System.IO;

public class FileSystemInfo
{
    private readonly Lazy<DriveInfo> dInfo =
        new Lazy<DriveInfo>(() => new DriveInfo(@"C:\"));

    public string CheckTotalFreeSpace()
    {
        return dInfo.Value.TotalFreeSpace.ToString();
    }

    public string CheckVolumeLabel()
    {
        return dInfo.Value.VolumeLabel.ToString();
    }
}
```